# Group by and determine which entries there are in a given group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Suppose you have a data frame `df` with 5 attributes: `x1, x2, x3, x4, Year`, as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
x1   <- 1:30
x2   <- rnorm(10)
x3   <- rchisq(25, 2, ncp = 0)
x4   <- rpois(6, 0.94)
Year <- sample(2011:2014,30,replace=TRUE)

noRow <- max(length(x1), length(x2), length(x3), length(x4), length(Year))

df <- list(x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, x4=x4, Year=Year)
attributes(df) <- list(names = names(df), row.names=1:30, class='data.frame')
```

and output

```
x1         x2        x3   x4 Year
1   1 -0.6264538 4.2807226    0 2014
2   2  0.1836433 1.6273105    0 2014
3   3 -0.8356286 0.3144031    0 2012
4   4  1.5952808 0.6216108    0 2012
5   5  0.3295078 0.9374638    1 2014
6   6 -0.8204684 0.1363947    2 2013
7   7  0.4874291 2.4985843 <NA> 2013
8   8  0.7383247 2.0162627 <NA> 2012
9   9  0.5757814 2.7218900 <NA> 2012
10 10 -0.3053884 2.4119764 <NA> 2014
11 11       <NA> 1.1082308 <NA> 2013
12 12       <NA> 2.4140052 <NA> 2011
13 13       <NA> 3.1249573 <NA> 2011
14 14       <NA> 0.2615523 <NA> 2012
15 15       <NA> 0.4381074 <NA> 2014
16 16       <NA> 0.6944394 <NA> 2013
17 17       <NA> 0.8599189 <NA> 2014
18 18       <NA> 0.2924151 <NA> 2013
19 19       <NA> 1.6834339 <NA> 2012
20 20       <NA> 0.4848175 <NA> 2012
21 21       <NA> 3.1606987 <NA> 2011
22 22       <NA> 2.3705121 <NA> 2011
23 23       <NA> 0.7808625 <NA> 2013
24 24       <NA> 0.4621734 <NA> 2011
25 25       <NA> 1.9421776 <NA> 2012
26 26       <NA>      <NA> <NA> 2013
27 27       <NA>      <NA> <NA> 2014
28 28       <NA>      <NA> <NA> 2012
29 29       <NA>      <NA> <NA> 2012
30 30       <NA>      <NA> <NA> 2011
```

I would like to group by year and determine if for a given year we have no entries in one or more attributes.
Using

```
library("dplyr")
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Year) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(count = n())
```

only gives me the number of entries in a given year, but it doesn't tell me the which attributes are present/non-missing in a given year. 
Thanks for sharing your ideas.

Wished output:

```
Year  x1   x2   x3   x4
2011   1    0    1    0
2012   1    1    1    1
2013   1    1    1    1
2014   1    1    1    1
```

where `1` means there's at least one entry for the variable in a given year, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: If by present you mean nonmissing, you can summarise_each (or some similar verb) with a function like sum(!is.na(x)) > 0

Comment: @Frank could you please provide an example?

Comment: It is up to you to provide a complete example in the question -- including the output you expect. I'm just taking a shot in the dark at what you're attempting.

Comment: @Frank fair point! I edited my post with the wished output. I tried doing this table using `dcast.data.table`, but it rather gives me the output 1 for each entry of variables.

Answer (score 0):

This code solves your problem:

```
df$attrib_ok <- !is.na(rowSums(df[1:4]))
df1 <- df %>%
        dplyr::group_by(Year) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(count=sum(attrib_ok)) %>%
        dplyr::select(-attrib_ok)
```

but it seems you have created a corrupt dataframe where this solution doesn`t work.
You have to create previously a non-corrupt dataframe like this:

```
set.seed(1)
x1   <- 1:30
x2   <- c(rnorm(10), rep(NA, 20))
x3   <- c(rchisq(25, 2, ncp = 0), rep(NA, 5))
x4   <- c(rpois(6, 0.94), rep(NA, 24))
Year <- sample(2011:2014,30,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,Year)
```

Code to get your wished output:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Year=df$Year,!is.na(df[1:4]))
df1 <- aggregate(.~Year, data = df1, FUN = sum)
df1 <- data.frame(Year=df1$Year, apply(apply(df1[,2:5], 2, as.logical), 2, as.numeric))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, this is not exactly what I want. Your solution returns how many times all four attributes are not NA in a given year. I would like to get is which attributes are not NA for each given year.

Comment: @mike.dl Can you just change the sum() in this answer to sum() > 0?